# How to add filters to charts in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-grid

I have followed the following example- [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/integrated-charts-cross-filtering/) to create a chart as shown. As you can see in the example, if you edit the table using filters, the charts also gets edited accordingly.

The issue that I am facing is, only the charts are getting displayed and not the table.

app.component.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="barChart" class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"></div>
  <div id="bubbleChart" class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"></div>
  <ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [enableCharts]="true"
    [chartThemes]="chartThemes"
    (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   gridApi: any;
   gridColumnApi: any;

   columnDefs: any;
   defaultColDef: any;
   rowData: any;
   chartThemes: any;

  constructor() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: 'city',
        chartDataType: 'category',
      },
      {
        field: 'country',
        chartDataType: 'category',
      },
      {
        field: 'longitude',
        chartDataType: 'series',
      },
      {
        field: 'latitude',
        chartDataType: 'series',
      },
      {
        field: 'population',
        chartDataType: 'series',
      },
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: 'agMultiColumnFilter',
      floatingFilter: true,
      resizable: true,
    };

    function getData() {
      return [
        {
          city: 'Tokyo',
          latitude: 35.6897,
          longitude: 139.6922,
          country: 'Japan',
          population: 37977000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Jakarta',
          latitude: -6.2146,
          longitude: 106.8451,
          country: 'Indonesia',
          population: 34540000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Delhi',
          latitude: 28.66,
          longitude: 77.23,
          country: 'India',
          population: 29617000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Mumbai',
          latitude: 18.9667,
          longitude: 72.8333,
          country: 'India',
          population: 23355000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Manila',
          latitude: 14.5958,
          longitude: 120.9772,
          country: 'Philippines',
          population: 23088000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Shanghai',
          latitude: 31.1667,
          longitude: 121.4667,
          country: 'China',
          population: 22120000,
        },
        {
          city: 'São Paulo',
          latitude: -23.5504,
          longitude: -46.6339,
          country: 'Brazil',
          population: 22046000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Seoul',
          latitude: 37.5833,
          longitude: 127,
          country: 'Korea, South',
          population: 21794000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Mexico City',
          latitude: 19.4333,
          longitude: -99.1333,
          country: 'Mexico',
          population: 20996000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Guangzhou',
          latitude: 23.1288,
          longitude: 113.259,
          country: 'China',
          population: 20902000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Beijing',
          latitude: 39.905,
          longitude: 116.3914,
          country: 'China',
          population: 19433000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Cairo',
          latitude: 30.0561,
          longitude: 31.2394,
          country: 'Egypt',
          population: 19372000,
        },
        {
          city: 'New York',
          latitude: 40.6943,
          longitude: -73.9249,
          country: 'United States',
          population: 18713220,
        },
        {
          city: 'Kolkāta',
          latitude: 22.5411,
          longitude: 88.3378,
          country: 'India',
          population: 17560000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Moscow',
          latitude: 55.7558,
          longitude: 37.6178,
          country: 'Russia',
          population: 17125000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Bangkok',
          latitude: 13.75,
          longitude: 100.5167,
          country: 'Thailand',
          population: 17066000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Buenos Aires',
          latitude: -34.5997,
          longitude: -58.3819,
          country: 'Argentina',
          population: 16157000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Shenzhen',
          latitude: 22.535,
          longitude: 114.054,
          country: 'China',
          population: 15929000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Dhaka',
          latitude: 23.7161,
          longitude: 90.3961,
          country: 'Bangladesh',
          population: 15443000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Lagos',
          latitude: 6.45,
          longitude: 3.4,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          population: 15279000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Istanbul',
          latitude: 41.01,
          longitude: 28.9603,
          country: 'Turkey',
          population: 15154000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Ōsaka',
          latitude: 34.6936,
          longitude: 135.5019,
          country: 'Japan',
          population: 14977000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Karachi',
          latitude: 24.86,
          longitude: 67.01,
          country: 'Pakistan',
          population: 14835000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Bangalore',
          latitude: 12.9699,
          longitude: 77.598,
          country: 'India',
          population: 13707000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Tehran',
          latitude: 35.7,
          longitude: 51.4167,
          country: 'Iran',
          population: 13633000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Ho Chi Minh City',
          latitude: 10.8167,
          longitude: 106.6333,
          country: 'Vietnam',
          population: 13312000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Los Angeles',
          latitude: 34.1139,
          longitude: -118.4068,
          country: 'United States',
          population: 12750807,
        },
        {
          city: 'Rio de Janeiro',
          latitude: -22.9083,
          longitude: -43.1964,
          country: 'Brazil',
          population: 12272000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Nanyang',
          latitude: 32.9987,
          longitude: 112.5292,
          country: 'China',
          population: 12010000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Chennai',
          latitude: 13.0825,
          longitude: 80.275,
          country: 'India',
          population: 11324000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Chengdu',
          latitude: 30.6636,
          longitude: 104.0667,
          country: 'China',
          population: 11309000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Lahore',
          latitude: 31.5497,
          longitude: 74.3436,
          country: 'Pakistan',
          population: 11021000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Paris',
          latitude: 48.8566,
          longitude: 2.3522,
          country: 'France',
          population: 11020000,
        },
        {
          city: 'London',
          latitude: 51.5072,
          longitude: -0.1275,
          country: 'United Kingdom',
          population: 10979000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Linyi',
          latitude: 35.0606,
          longitude: 118.3425,
          country: 'China',
          population: 10820000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Tianjin',
          latitude: 39.1467,
          longitude: 117.2056,
          country: 'China',
          population: 10800000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Shijiazhuang',
          latitude: 38.0422,
          longitude: 114.5086,
          country: 'China',
          population: 10784600,
        },
        {
          city: 'Baoding',
          latitude: 38.8671,
          longitude: 115.4845,
          country: 'China',
          population: 10700000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Zhoukou',
          latitude: 33.625,
          longitude: 114.6418,
          country: 'China',
          population: 9901000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Hyderābād',
          latitude: 17.3667,
          longitude: 78.4667,
          country: 'India',
          population: 9746000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Weifang',
          latitude: 36.7167,
          longitude: 119.1,
          country: 'China',
          population: 9373000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Nagoya',
          latitude: 35.1167,
          longitude: 136.9333,
          country: 'Japan',
          population: 9113000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Wuhan',
          latitude: 30.5872,
          longitude: 114.2881,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8962000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Heze',
          latitude: 35.2333,
          longitude: 115.4333,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8750000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Ganzhou',
          latitude: 25.8292,
          longitude: 114.9336,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8677600,
        },
        {
          city: 'Tongshan',
          latitude: 34.261,
          longitude: 117.1859,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8669000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Chicago',
          latitude: 41.8373,
          longitude: -87.6862,
          country: 'United States',
          population: 8604203,
        },
        {
          city: 'Fuyang',
          latitude: 32.8986,
          longitude: 115.8045,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8360000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Jining',
          latitude: 35.4,
          longitude: 116.5667,
          country: 'China',
          population: 8023000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Dongguan',
          latitude: 23.0475,
          longitude: 113.7493,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7981000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Hanoi',
          latitude: 21.0245,
          longitude: 105.8412,
          country: 'Vietnam',
          population: 7785000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Pune',
          latitude: 18.5196,
          longitude: 73.8553,
          country: 'India',
          population: 7764000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Chongqing',
          latitude: 29.55,
          longitude: 106.5069,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7739000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Changchun',
          latitude: 43.9,
          longitude: 125.2,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7674439,
        },
        {
          city: 'Zhumadian',
          latitude: 32.9773,
          longitude: 114.0253,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7640000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Ningbo',
          latitude: 29.875,
          longitude: 121.5492,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7639000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Onitsha',
          latitude: 6.1667,
          longitude: 6.7833,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          population: 7635000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Hefei',
          latitude: 31.8639,
          longitude: 117.2808,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7457027,
        },
        {
          city: 'Ahmadābād',
          latitude: 23.03,
          longitude: 72.58,
          country: 'India',
          population: 7410000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Nantong',
          latitude: 31.9829,
          longitude: 120.8873,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7282835,
        },
        {
          city: 'Foshan',
          latitude: 23.0292,
          longitude: 113.1056,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7194311,
        },
        {
          city: 'Hengyang',
          latitude: 26.8968,
          longitude: 112.5857,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7148344,
        },
        {
          city: 'Xi’an',
          latitude: 34.2667,
          longitude: 108.9,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7135000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Shenyang',
          latitude: 41.8039,
          longitude: 123.4258,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7105000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Tangshan',
          latitude: 39.6292,
          longitude: 118.1742,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7100000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Shaoyang',
          latitude: 27.2418,
          longitude: 111.4725,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7071000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Changsha',
          latitude: 28.1987,
          longitude: 112.9709,
          country: 'China',
          population: 7044118,
        },
        {
          city: 'Cangzhou',
          latitude: 38.3037,
          longitude: 116.8452,
          country: 'China',
          population: 6800000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Maoming',
          latitude: 21.6618,
          longitude: 110.9178,
          country: 'China',
          population: 6706000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Huanggang',
          latitude: 30.45,
          longitude: 114.875,
          country: 'China',
          population: 6667000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Miami',
          latitude: 25.7839,
          longitude: -80.2102,
          country: 'United States',
          population: 6445545,
        },
        {
          city: 'Sūrat',
          latitude: 21.17,
          longitude: 72.83,
          country: 'India',
          population: 5807000,
        },
        {
          city: 'Dallas',
          latitude: 32.7936,
          longitude: -96.7662,
          country: 'United States',
          population: 5743938,
        },
      ];
    }

    this.rowData = getData();
    this.chartThemes = ['ag-default-dark'];
  }

  onFirstDataRendered(params: any) {
    createColumnChart(params.api);
    createBubbleChart(params.api);
  }

  onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }
}

function createColumnChart(gridApi: any) {
  gridApi.createCrossFilterChart({
    chartType: 'column',
    cellRange: {
      columns: ['country', 'population'],
    },
    aggFunc: 'count',
    chartThemeOverrides: {
      common: {
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'Number of Most Populous Cities by Country',
        },
        legend: { enabled: false },
      },
      cartesian: { axes: { category: { label: { rotation: 325 } } } },
    },
    chartContainer: document.querySelector('#barChart'),
  });
}
function createBubbleChart(gridApi: any) {
  gridApi.createCrossFilterChart({
    chartType: 'bubble',
    cellRange: {
      columns: ['longitude', 'latitude', 'population'],
    },
    chartThemeOverrides: {
      common: {
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'Latitude vs Longitude of Most Populous Cities',
        },
        legend: { enabled: false },
      },
    },
    chartContainer: document.querySelector('#bubbleChart'),
  });
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
'''
```

Comment: Can you please provide stackblitz url ?